# From where do we get the fortify360 (SSC) Installer

Tags: fortify

I want to install SSC(fortify 360) on a Apache tomcat server.How do i do it? can anyone please give me the link where to find the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is provided in HP's MySoftware center, if you are licensed for it.
https://h20576.www2.hpe.com/mysoftware/download/downloadCenter